# Bind both click and enter key for accessibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, tabindex

Given a form (please note the `tabindex` property)

```
<form id="settings-form">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
    <a href="#" class="cancel-save" tabindex="0">cancel</a>
</form>
```

Binding an action to the cancel button

```
$('#settings-form').find('.cancel-save').click(function(){ alert('CANCEL SAVE'); });
```

Now, when a user wants to cancel the changes, he will simply click the "cancel" button. But if he navigates with the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key and then hit enter the alert doesn't come up.

Is there a "master event" for this kind of actions, to handle both enter, clicks, spaces, etc., whatever accessibility features a user might have, without converting the `<a>` into a `<button>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the cancel button do? If it's purpose is to reset the values in the form, you should really use a HTML input type of reset instead, in order for this to work for non-JS users:

You can then bind to the form reset event and use prevent default if you want to give JS users a richer experience, but non-JS users still get expected behaviour. In general, an anchor that does nothing without JavaScript could probably be implemented better (or at least injected via JavaScript), especially if you're concerned with accessibility.

```
<form id="theForm">
    <input type="text" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value=""/>
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>

$("#theForm").bind("reset", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Fancy reset handler
});
```

By default, this should include mouse, keyboard or touch interaction, as you're binding to the form event.

Comment: +1 to this. To Grigore: using a link instead of a button, you have to use `<a href="#" class="cancel-save" tabindex="0" role="button">cancel</a>` or use a `reset` like Dave mentioned. Accessibility issues are easier to solve if you start with semantic code

Comment: Accepting this answer as solution because of Ryan B's comment. The `role="button"` is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Hi Grigore, just to note that what you're using is described in the specification as "a poor use of the role attribute because it attempts to apply semantics of an element that already exists onto some other element … Although the role attribute may be used to add semantics to an element, authors SHOULD use elements with inherent semantics, such as `<p>`, rather than layering semantics on semantically neutral elements, such as `<div role="paragraph">`.". You can read more on this if interested here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-role/#s_role_module_attributes

Comment: +1 to Dave's comment. I am sorry that I didn't explain it that thoroughly. @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL, please use the `<insert type='reset'>`.

Comment: @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL: Yes, he means `<input>`.

Answer (score 3):

To bind to both, you can define multiple events (in a space-separated list) in the first parameter of the `on()` method:

```
$('#settings-form').find('.cancel-save').on('keypress click',
    function(e){
        var eType = e.type;
        if (eType == 'click' || (eType == 'keypress' && e.which == 13)) {
            alert('CANCEL SAVE');
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KNk8W/).

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on).